# ways to run a cron/curl command in a chroot jail

Tags: php, curl, cron, chroot

Any creative ways to run a cron job using curl from within a chroot jail?
I need to fire a php script every 5 minutes for a time based module I built for work. My parent company has placed my slice of the server in a chroot environment.

Any ways I can do this without access to the top level directory?

Comment: Do you have cron installed or permission to install it within the chrooted env? Also do you actually need to invoke the php script with `curl`? It is only necessary if you need to invoke a script on a remote server.

Comment: I can set up a cron via an admin panle (plesk/parellels environment) but when I run the cron job I get an email from the daemon saying the file can't be found.  I know the absolute path is correct in the browser but it is probably not correct from the needed files/libraries on the server, hence the file not found error.

Comment: I do need this script to automatically run every 5 minutes.  It's pushing content from that server to a cdn and the content it pushes is pulled from a db.  The content is time related.